# Most Effective Way to Replace Case-When in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have data table having more than 300 million records (32 fields) and contains data for only 6 months of 2019 which means it intend to grow further. Data insertion frequency is "daily" (almost 2 million records per day). In order to make it useful for front end users, I need to make an additional column called "Product Name". This column drives using 6 columns (or less) and I've more than 47 products as of now. Currently I've created a VIEW on table using Case-When, but 1) it is too costly while querying the view and on 2) sometimes it overwrites the existing product because of too many combinations.

I've solved query cost problem by an ambiguous way of maintaining last 90 days data into another table (along with derived column) but It has created other problems 1) it is taking additional disk space 2) in case of product overwritten, I've to truncate the complete table and have to re-insert the complete 90 days data after fixing the VIEW. This exercise take too much time.

Please suggest some good useful tips to get rid of these problems.

If there is a way to replace case-when which is more efficient
    and help me to get rid of products overwritten or at-least help me
    to track if any product is going to be overwritten.

Here is sample code (VIEW) of few products and I've 47 products as of now

```
    SELECT [A], 
   CAST(LEFT([DATE TIME], 9) + ' ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING([DATE TIME], CHARINDEX(' ', [DATE TIME]) + 1, 8), '.', ':') + ' ' + RIGHT([DATE TIME], 2) AS DATETIME) AS [TRXN DATETIME], 
   [B], 
   [C], 
   [D], 
   [E], 
   [F], 
   [TYPE], 
   [CATEGORY], 
   MEDIUM, 
   [G], 
   [SENDER], 
   [RECEIVER], 
   FEE,
   DISCOUNT,
   CASE
       WHEN(t.[TYPE] = 'P'
            AND t.[CATEGORY] = 'Ea'
            AND t.MEDIUM IN('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh'))
       THEN 'Easy'
       WHEN(t.[TYPE] = 'P'
            AND t.[CATEGORY] = 'Po'
            AND t.MEDIUM IN('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh'))
       THEN 'Post'
       WHEN(t.[TYPE] = 'PHYSICAL_CARD'
            AND t.[CATEGORY] IS NULL
            AND t.MEDIUM IN('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh'))
       THEN 'Card'
       WHEN(t.[TYPE] = 'DEBIT'
            AND t.[CATEGORY] IS NULL
            AND t.MEDIUM IN('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh')
            AND t.[RECEIVER] = 'xyz')
       THEN 'Payment'
   END AS [PRODUCT NAME] FROM dbo.ProductEvents AS t;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
I've added some of code I'm using in VIEW. Please see if this could help you to understand the problem

Comment: @AnwaarEMustafa, what do you mean by ""overwrites the existing product because of too many combinations"?

Comment: @DanGuzman it means for example "DEBIT" type can have multiple [CATEGORIES] and [RECEIVERS]
so today:
TYPE: DEBIT, CATEGORY: NULL, RECEIVER: X will be "Product A"
next day if another MEDIUM for example 'zz' is added then it would not be marked as "Product A".

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

As I can see you have a common checking for all CASE is-

```
AND t.MEDIUM IN('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh')
```

For an immediate improvement, you can remove that checking from all CASE condition and add in the WHERE condition at the end as below-

```
WHERE t.MEDIUM IN('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh')
```

**Second:**

You can apply Index on three column - [TYPE],[CATEGORY] and [MEDIUM]. This will obviously add some query performance.

**Third:**

considering huge amount of data transaction, the best option is to add a new column Payment or [Payment Type] to your database table. Then Update all existing record's new column with the same logic you are now selecting data.

For new records, not sure how almost 2M records are coming each day. Either from Application's LIVE transaction OR from a ETL like process. For both case, you can populate the Payment Type while inserting data into the table. For populating Payment, you can add a lookup table to holds all logic to populate Payment during insertion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion buddy.
1. first solution would not work because medium differs for each [product type] so I have to add it in each case-when statement
2. indexes  are already there
3. 2 million records are coming through ETL. Considering lookup table, I have to create multiple lookup tables in my case. would it be efficient to create multiple joins with lookup tables?

Comment: 3. Yes, as once data is populated - you no longer required applying all those CASE statements again and and while selected data.